# Spring Boot 3 KafkaTemplate tracing (traceId, spanId, baggage) is missing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-micrometer

Prior to Spring Boot 3, tracing, including Kafka tracing, was performed using Sleuth.
It was possible to propagate a tracing context (traceId, spanId, baggage) over Kafka.

Sleuth no longer exists. Spring Boot now takes care of these aspects.

It seems that tracing on the producer side (KafkaTemplate) disappeared.

This was previously handled using a template post-processor. See KafkaFactoryBeanPostProcessor,
TraceProducerPostProcessor and TracingConsumerPostProcessor for more technical details

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/tree/80f0889c91d337e84ce0eca2d602464a1a4355c6/spring-cloud-sleuth-brave/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/brave/instrument/messaging

Have I forgotten something? Should I configure it manually or import another dependency?

Any comments or feedback are more than welcome on this tricky topic.

EDIT 1:

By adding brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients into the classpath, it's also possible to setup it manually using the following portion of code

```
@Bean
public <K, V> ProducerFactory<K, V> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, ObjectProvider<Tracing> tracing) {
    final var factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
        tracing.ifAvailable(t -> {
            final var kafkaTracing = KafkaTracing.create(t);
            factory.addPostProcessor(kafkaTracing::producer);
        });
        return factory;
}
```

Comment: Manually adding the TraceProducerPostProcessor is fixing the issue (trace context is propagated when using that post processor). Not clear who is supposed to take care of that aspect. Spring Boot, Spring kafka or Micrometer?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observation is not enabled on Spring Kafka components by default.

See `KafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true)`.

More in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/3.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/micrometer.html#observation

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Enabling the observation is not solving this issue. The trace context is not propagated . A trace context is created on the producer side but this one is not propagated (causing another trace context creation with another traceId) on the consumer side. So, by adding the post processor, this context is propagated through Kafka headers. I'm using the brave implementation with the b3 type.

Comment: Then the `observationEnabled = true`  must be set on the consumer side via `ContainerProperties`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/3.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/container-props.html#page-title

Comment: Observation is enabled on both sides. I'm trying to setup a basic project to showcase the propagation from the producer side to the consumer side. Showing both the traceId and spanId into the log entries of the same flow.

Comment: Same issue with a basic produce/consume application. A traceContext should be propagated over Kafka using Kafka headers but this is not the case. Due to this, another trace context is created on the consumer side. By adding the post processor like Sleuth did, the original context is correctly propagated. So, looks like a bug in Spring Boot or Spring Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. The observation support is working fine when enabled.

I used the setter on the template to enable it but the property mapper used in the auto configuration was resetting the value to false.

```
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                         ObservationRegistry observationRegistry,
                                         ProducerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaProducerFactory,
                                         ProducerListener<Object, Object> kafkaProducerListener,
                                         ObjectProvider<RecordMessageConverter> messageConverter) {
    PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get().alwaysApplyingWhenNonNull();
    KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerFactory);

    kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true);
    messageConverter.ifUnique(kafkaTemplate::setMessageConverter);
    map.from(kafkaProducerListener).to(kafkaTemplate::setProducerListener);
    map.from(kafkaProperties.getTemplate().getDefaultTopic()).to(kafkaTemplate::setDefaultTopic);
    map.from(kafkaProperties.getTemplate().getTransactionIdPrefix()).to(kafkaTemplate::setTransactionIdPrefix);
    map.from(kafkaProperties.getTemplate().isObservationEnabled()).to(kafkaTemplate::setObservationEnabled); // RESET THE FLAG TO FALSE IF NOT SET INTO THE PROPERTIES
    return kafkaTemplate;
}
```

So, in brief, this was due to a wrong re-definition of the KafkaTemplate ("copy pasted" from the default auto configuration) into a custom auto-configuration. I didn't pay attention to the PropertyMapper.